# Missing Python 3.7 shared library

Tags: python, python-3.7

Running Ubuntu 18.04. Need to access the Python 3.7 shared object file. First I did:

```
sudo apt install python3
[...]

emil@emil-Gazelle:/usr/local/lib$ ldconfig -p | grep python
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
    libpython3.6m.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
    libpyglib-2.0-python2.7.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyglib-2.0-python2.7.so.0
```

So it looks like Python 3.6 is installed. I need 3.7. I followed the guide at https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/, and it installs Python 3.7 successfully:

```
emil@emil-Gazelle:/usr/local/lib$ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.4

sudo ldconfig && ldconfig -p | grep python
```

still yields the same thing, so my program can't access the shared object file. How can I install Python 3.7 in such a way that it exposes the library file?

Comment: Wild guess, when you did `make -j 1`, the linker files and shared libraries should be stored somewhere, you'll have to move them manually to wherever you want them. Since ubuntu and I'm guessing the `altinstall` step in the makefile only installs the end user runtimes, not the development files *(usually `python3-dev` package in Ubuntu and some other distros)*. So try `find ./ -iname "*.so"` when you're standing in your build folder.

Comment: @Torxed looking at another install guide. one had --enable-shared in ./configure. maybe it will do the trick as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I had to ./configure with --enables-shared, which solved the issue.

Comment: * --enable-shared